# Develop hybrid mobile application

Tags: mobile

I am an iOS developer and I have decided to develop one hybrid mobile application which will support all mobile platforms (Android, Blackberry, iOS, and Windows Phone). I want to display my results in a table view through XML parsing and have the application look like [this](http://itunes.apple.com/au/app/vision-asia./id447573755?mt=8#).

If this is possible, which framework could I develop with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/). Its a very mature mobile app frame work with a very active community. They support any mobile that uses the webkit based browser which is everything on your list(WP7 is on their list, I think it will be supported in Sencha 2).

Sencha 2 which will be released by the end of october will have its own native packaging library, so the use of phonegap wont be required. But it works well with phone gap if preferred.

Comment: sir would you pls suggest me can we use native html code in sencha touch because i am not a webdeveloper but i know basic html

Comment: Well Sencha is a javacsript framework. Javascript basically create the html dynamically. Dynamic websites can't be really done with just html. JS is sort of a requirement for web development. A webapp is the only way I think you can go if you are trying to target multiple os with the same app. There is another framework named Titanium which allows us to use JS to develop app for multiple os's.